# pytest: how to use a mark to inject a fixture?

Tags: python, hook, pytest, fixtures

I'm writing a pytest plugin with a fixture that has a side effect of setting up some desirable mocks. I'd like to write a simple mark that will allow the user to call this fixture setup before the test runs, without having to include the fixture in the test function parameters -- essentially, "injecting" the fixture using a mark. My reasoning is that the user may want the mocked setup without needing the return value of the fixture itself, in which case it seems more intuitive to me to use a mark than to require that they declare a fixture they won't be using.

How might I use a mark to require a fixture in pytest? Looking at the docs, it seems like I want to hook into something like `pytest_collection_modifyitems`, check for the relevant mark on each item using `Item.iter_markers`, and then somehow update the list of fixtures. Reading the code, however, I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly to trigger that fixture setup.

Here's a simplified example of what the fixture in question looks like:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mocks(mocker):
    ret_val = 10
    mocker.patch('path.to.patch', return_value=ret_val)
    return ret_val
```

Here's what the user can do to set up the mocks now:

```
def test_mocks(mocks):
    # 'path.to.patch' will be mocked in this test
    # ... test code ...
```

But here's what the test might look like if the fixture could be triggered via a mark instead:

```
@pytest.mark.mocks
def test_mocks():
    # 'path.to.patch' will be mocked in this test, too
    # ... test code ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to implement this by using the [`pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=hooks#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) to adjust the list of fixtures on the test item after collection:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    '''
    Check if any tests are marked to use the mock.
    '''
    for item in items:
        if item.get_closest_marker('mocks'):
            item.fixturenames.append('mocks')
```

Adjusting the `Item.fixturenames` list after collection appears to trigger the fixture setup in the way I was hoping.

If you don't care about using a custom mark, however, @hoefling's recommendation to use the built-in `usefixtures` mark would be a good solution, too.

Comment: Now `get_marker` is removed, use `get_closest_marker`

Answer (score 9):

Use the `usefixtures` marker:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def mocks(mocker):
    mocker.patch('os.path.isdir', return_value=True)

# test_me.py
import os
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('mocks')
def test_mocks():
    assert os.path.isdir('/this/is/definitely/not/a/dir')
```

Passing multiple fixtures is also posible:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('mocks', 'my_other_fixture', 'etc')
```

However, there is a caveat: the `mocks` fixture in your code returns a value `ret_val`. When passing the fixture via test function args, this value is returned under the `mocks` arg; when you use markers, you don't have the arg anymore, so you won't be able to use the value. Should you be needing the mock value, pass the fixture in the test function args. There are some other ways imaginable, like passing `ret_val` via cache, however, the resulting code will be more complicated and less readable so I wouldn't bother.

Comment: This is a great workaround! For the API I'm writing, however, I do want to expose the custom mark. I'll recommend your solution as a good alternative when I post my answer.

Comment: Oh, I didn't quite understand from the question that the custom marker is a requirement - thought you just need _some_ marker :-) However, I like your answer a lot, it's the best way to implement it IMO.